# Is it possible to create smaller memory-mapped views on a 2GB+ file?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I have written a C++ class for Windows and Linux that creates a memory-mapped view for an file of arbitrary size n. The code for the class constructor [can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/2GX0XHsm). I am currently testing the code on Windows 32 bit XP.

I have found for file sizes 0 < n <= 1.7GB , the constructor returns a valid pointer to a memory-mapped view. However, for a file size >= 2 GB, MapViewOfFile returns a NULL value and an error code of 8, "Not enough storage is available to process this command". Evidently, Windows cannot find an available address space of size 2 GB in the process.

Therefore, I may need to modify the class constructor to create a set of smaller memory-mapped views totaling >= 2GB bytes && < 2 ^ 32 - 1 bytes. The other requirement is to create a mapping between each of the smaller memory-mapped views and a randomly accessed address in the  process' address space.

Previously, I used the following code for random access:

```
char* KeyArray;

try {
    mmapFile = new cMemoryMappedFile(n);
}
catch (cException e)
{
    throw;
}

KeyArray = (char *)(mmapFile->GetPointer());
KeyArray[i] = ...
```

How should I modify the class to handle these requirements?

Comment: Here is the pastebin url. <iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=2GX0XHsm" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>

Comment: [Here is a working link directly to the code](http://pastebin.com/2GX0XHsm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your pastebin link, but I can suggest a simple solution with a c++ class declaration. I think the implementation should be obvious from the comments:

```
class ShiftingMemMap
{
public:
    // constructs a dynamically shifting memory map of a file...
    ShiftingMemMap ( const char* fileName, size_t view_size = 4096 );

    // retrieve/set a byte at the given file offset. If the offset is not currently in-view,
    // shift the view to encompass the offset. The reference should not be stored for later
    // access because the view may need to shift again...
    byte& operator [] ( unsigned int_64_t offset );

private:
    int_64_t current_offset;
    size_t current_size;
};
```

All that being said, you could write a class that returns multiple views of a file to allow saving a reference for later and also editing different parts of the file simultaneously without having to shift the view back and forth repeatedly.

```
class MemMap
{
public:
    MemMap ( const char* filename );

    shared_ptr<MemMapView> View ( unsigned int_64_t offset, size_t size = 4096 );
};

class MemMapView
{
public:
    char& operator[] ( size_t offset );
};
```

Comment: royce3, My supervisor told me to solve this problem without using Boost because our potential product will have to run on Windows, Linux , Oracle Solaris Unix, IBM AIX UNIX & HPUX. On Windows and Linux we are using the latest releases. However, on Oracle Solaris UNIX & HPUX, the cost of getting the latest UNIX distribution is prohibitively high so we cannot use BOOST on Oracle Solaris UNIX & HPUX. However, last week we were able to solve this problem using STL and our own doubly linked class which has a custom memory allocator. Thank you for your reply.Frank Chang

Comment: royce3, I just accepted your answer because I thought it was excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you want can be achieved using repaging, see how it is done in boost.iostreams [here](http://cnx.org/content/m15849/latest/).

Comment: Thank you for your  reply. We cannot use boost until we obtain approval for the lastest Solaris Unix, IBM AIX and HPUX licenses. i am apologize for not mentioning that. Could we look at the boost code and adapt it for Windows , Linux and Unix? Thank you.

Comment: I found a repaging example for boost.iostreams serial access. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You only *have* 2GB (or 3GB, with some tweaks) of user process space on a 32-bit OS. Period. That is a hard limitation, and no amount of creating many smaller mappings can get around that. You will need to shift your mapping around in order to access the different parts of the file. But it will still be faster than seeking, reading, and writing.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: not the mapping has to be shifted, but the view. Or am I mistaken? ... oh, sorry just noticed it's shared between Linux and Windows, not sure from the top off my head in how far this applies also to Linux.

Comment: Yes, on Win32 it would be the view that needs to be shifted.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: hehe, same thought. Had edited my comment and yours appeared ;)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Yes, I only want to access 2 ^ 32 - 1 bytes of address space. Could you suggest how I could shift my mappinf around in order to access the access the different parts of the file? Also, why will this be faster than seeking and reading from a file? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You *cannot* access 2**32-1 bytes of address space on a 32-bit system. Some of it is reserved for libraries and the kernel, and some of it is in use by the process.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquex-Abrams, Thank you for your reply. Does that mean if I want to access 2**32 -1 bytes , we should seek, read and write to a file. Thank you.

Comment: No, it means that you need to shift the mapping or view around.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazeuez-Abrams , How do we shift the mapping or view around? Thank you for your reply?

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to work. You simply cannot use all of the 4 GiB of address space on 32 bit Windows. Redesign your access to the array to map just small views of the large file.

Comment: wilx, I only want to use address space < 2 ^ 32 - 1 bytes. Is that possible? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Frank: yes, on Windows it would be. The mapping can stretch the whole file, while the view can theoretically be up to 2 GiB. But given that some entities already live inside your process memory space, I doubt you will get up to 2 GiB proper.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, Could you advise us how move the view within the mapping? Thank you for answer,

Comment: @Frank: Simply use `UnmapViewOfFile` and then again `MapViewOfFile` to map a different region of the file.

Comment: @wilk, I have modified the class to utilize your answer. I am interested in minimizing the number of times UnmapViewOfFile and MapViewOfFile is called. One way is to enlarge the viewport size. Are there any other methods(i.e caching) which we could use to minimize the time penalty associated with calling UnmapViewOfFile/MapViewOfFile many times. The pastebin url for modified class is: <script src="http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=YTKYrFGG"></script> Thank you for your answer

Comment: @wilk, I didn't embed the pastebin url correctly. It works if you start the url with <script src= </script>. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Benchmark your code with different view sizes to find the best size of the view for your application.

Comment: @Frank: You have to design your data file so it has locality of reference. If you have commonly accessed parts you can map those separately and have one view that moves around as needed, which you hopefully don't have to use much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  it is possible to write a C++ class for Windows,Solaris Unix, Linux that creates a memory-mapped view for an file of arbitrary size n. We just finished building two version of class, one using STL and the other one which my boss wrote which does not use STL. Both versions are better than using the heap when the size of the memory allocation is 1 gigabyte or more on 32 bit Windows, Linux, Solaris Unix. 
        Both of these version are also compatible with 64 bit Windows, Linux, Solaris Unix.
        If you want to find out more details about this, please email me at frankchang91@gmail.com. Massachusetts, USA. these 2 versions were independently designed and may become part of a data fusion US patent filing.